# Toggling value inside React component with useState not working

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component. Inside that component, I want something to grow and shrink every second. I'm trying to use useState for that.

This code does not work. It just repeatedly sets the value to false. I cannot quite figure out why. Any thoughts?

```
  const [fullWidth, setFullWidth] = useState(false);

  let interval;
  useEffect(() => {
    startToggle();
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, []);

  const startToggle = () => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setFullWidth(!fullWidth);
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it sets it to `false`, not `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `startToggle` is declared outside `useEffect` it is still required to pass `fullWidth` as a dependency inside effect array.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [fullWidth, setFullWidth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setFullWidth((f) => !f);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return fullWidth.toString();
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In that case it would be better to pass `fullWidth` to `startToggle` explicitly to make it ... more explicit. Alternatively,  `setFullWidth(fullWidth => !fullWidth);` could also be used.

Comment: @FelixKling This is cool since then we dont have to change the dependency array. However, what about hook principle - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies Is that rule not broken here, Felix?

Comment: @FelixKling your solution worked. Why does this make a difference?

Comment: @kinduser: I guess it is. But it also doesn't feel necessary to create a new interval on every render if we can already get the "current" value a different way, IMO. But everyone can choose what works for them :)

Comment: @JSeabolt: In your solution the interval is only started once on first render and `startToggle` (from the first render) will always reference the `fullWidth` from that first render call, when it had value `false`. By passing a callback function you are telling `setFullWidth` to give you the *current* value of that state. It's a common trap to fall into.

Comment: @JSeabolt Improved my answer a bit to follow what Felix suggested. The interval isnt re-created anymore with every render.